# matlab: using function hints in .net assembly

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I load c# assembly to matlab, there is hint like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwAIw.png) to complete name of classes and function, but not arguments. Is there some workaround to show method signature?

Answer (score 1):

> And, I've read that I can't unload assembly, is there some workaround about this? **edit:** *this part was removed from the question.*

You can start a **new Matlab instance** from Matlab itself with a system call and the [Matlab command line options](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html) and only load the libraries in the new instance. This is described in an answer to the qestion: [Release a .NET assembly from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617456/5276734)

Comment: Posting the same exact answer on three questions is not appropriate.