# Release a .NET assembly from MATLAB

Tags: c#, matlab

I am working on a small MATLAB project interfacing with a C# dll library.
MATLAB documentation allows you to load an assembly as described here:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/net.addassembly.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop and http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/an-assembly-is-a-library-of-net-classes.html

and my call for example is as follows:

```
NET.addAssembly('C:\MyLibrary.dll');
```

Everything is fine up to here, I can even debug in VS by attaching to MATLAB process, however there is a small issue. There is no 'removeAssembly' method to disconnect the assembly from MATLAB process. If I want to make a change in VS, I have to restart MATLAB to unlock the DLL which is really a pain in the b~~t. I even tried to use unlocker software with no luck..MATLAB freezes.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unloading an assembly is not possible, it's one of the [known limitations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-net-support.html)

Comment: oh no...anyway though thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

You can start a **new Matlab instance** from Matlab itself with a system call and the [Matlab command line options](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html). Then you can test your .NET libraries within the new instance. When the new instance is closed after your test, the .NET libraries are released. With this workaround, you don't need to reopen Matlab completely. Do not load the .NET assembly in the main Matlab instance.

Open a new Matlab instance (whole IDE GUI) on a **Windows PC**:

```
log_str = '-logfile "C:\Temp\logfile.txt"';
system_str = [ 'matlab.exe -nosplash ' log_str ];
system(system_str);
```

Automatically execute an m-File in the new Matlab instance via `-r`, without the IDE GUI with `-nodesktop` and have the new instance close itself after your test:

```
log_str = '-logfile "C:\Temp\logfile.txt"';
my_file = 'C:\Temp\test.m';
system_str = [ 'matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run(''' my_file '''), pause(2), exit" ' log_str ];
system(system_str);
```

The logfile logs the console output of the Matlab instance. It is optional, but helpful for testing. If you want your child instances to be asynchronous (i.e. returning the handle to the main Matlab instance), you can add `' &'` at the end of the `system_str`.